Tengo un monorepo con nx que tiene nexrtjs y espress y no se que he hehco pero ya no se ejecuta porque me dice que Joi.object es undefined
Este es el repositorio
El monorepo tiene varias librerias uan de ella es joi que ahi se crean los esquemas y luego web y api importan joi y sus esquemas. El proyecto de web no hay problema al compilar ni ejecutar pero el de api al ejecutarlo me da error:
export const createUserSchema = Joi.object({
^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'object')
El editor no muestra ningun error ni al compilar muestra errores es solo al ejecutar el proyecto api ya no se que hacer llevo todo el fin de semana peleandome haciendo commit y arreglo un error i sale otro pero todos es al compilar o ejecutar el proyecto de api
